# Wird das l bei "im Detail" gesprochen?

Tags: pronunciation

Ich habe schon mehrmals bemerkt, dass der Ausdruck *im Detail* [im Detai] ausgesprochen wird. Stimmt das oder habe ich es falsch gehört?

Den letzten Anlass zu dieser Annahme gab mir  [dieses Video](https://youtu.be/4pO3GWsvcbg) (ab 0:40)

Comment: Das aus dem Französischen kommende *ail(l)* wird im Deutschen *aij* gesprochen, so auch in *Taille*, *Kanaille*, *Journaille*.

Comment: @Janka: Aus meiner Erfahrung (Berlin) gibt es da einen deutlichen Unterschied, je nachdem das Wort auf -ail oder -aille endet. Im ersten Fall wird das Schluss-l unterschlagen, im zweiten verwandelt sich das i vor zu einem j hinter dem doppel-l, also Detai und Serai, aber Tallje, Kanallje, Journallje etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wie dir vermutlich die meisten Wörtbücher sagen werden, ist die Aussprache, die du vernommen hast, korrekt. [Duden z.B.:](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Detail)

> Lautschrift: [deˈtaɪ̯], auch: [deˈtaːj], österreichisch: [deˈtaɪ̯l]

Die Anmerkung zum Österreichischen kann ich übrigens auch selbst bestätigen. Hier in Österreich wird das Wort mit dem L gesprochen. Vielleicht bist du ja diese Aussprache gewöhnt oder hast das öfter gehört.

Comment: Die Aussprache mit -l ist nicht nur in Österreich gebräuchlich. Ich würde eher sagen: In nachlässiger Alltagssprache spricht man das -l mit. Will man dagegen gepflegeter sprechen (etwa bei einem wissenschaftlichen Vortrag, bei einer Hochzeitsrede oder im Rundfunk) wird man die als eleganter und gebildeter geltende französische Aussprache wählen.